# How to use Odoo XML-RPC in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, odoo, xml-rpc

I am currently working on Odoo mobile app development using Xamarin.

I need to fetch datas from Odoo server with help of C#

The Odoo official document supports only python,ruby,php and java

**reference -** https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html

There is no official document available for C#. So its possible to develop the Odoo mobile apps using Xamarin ?

I hope it possible. But I don't know how to develop without official documents. Anyone help me out?

Comment: There are a number of C# `XML-RPC` clients available such as http://xml-rpc.net

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for your suggestion